# PHP Logout redirection issue

Tags: php, html, sql

I am having a problem with my php file to log a user out. It is meant to redirect the user to the login page but it doesn't. I have all the files in the correct folder too on my web server. My code is as follows:

```
<?
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();

header("location:Student_Website_Login.html");
exit();
?>
```

Would really appreciate some feedback on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: First use `<?php` instead of `<?`. second: what's the error thrown?

Comment: `header("Location: http://www.google.de");` May the uppercase L and the space be the problem?

Comment: Try removing the `?>` in the last line..

Comment: This should help! http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: The missing <?php tag was the problem. Thanks!